# Creating a txt file for certain type of files using batch

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file

I have a folder containing all types of files. Let's say my folder path is `E:/temp`.

I would like to create, only for the `.avi` type files, a txt file and name the txt file as the name of the movie. so if I have 20 clip `.avi` files in the folder, I want to open 20 txt file, and each txt file will be named after a clip.

Also, inside the txt file I need to write (for all txt file it will be the same) the word "HAPPY"

What will be the script using batch file?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `FOR` to iterate over the elements you want to work with. See [How to loop through files matching wildcard in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39615/how-to-loop-through-files-matching-wildcard-in-batch-file) for details.

Once you have that part solved, you'll want to create the filename of your `.txt` file. The command line documentation of `FOR` can help us here:

```
In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been enhanced.
You can now use the following optional syntax:

    %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
    %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
    %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
    %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
    %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
```

The last entry is what we want. We want to cut off the `.avi`, so we use `~n` in our variable to get only the name. This is where the `%%~nf.txt` comes from.

We start with `%%f`, the current filename. Then we cut off the extension with `%%~nf` and tack on the `.txt`... Done: `%%~nf.txt`

The last problem is when you try to solve it all on one line, like:

```
FOR %%f IN (*.avi) DO ECHO HAPPY > %%~nf.txt
```

That wouldn't work, because the shell will interpret the `>` and start outputting to that file instantly, which is not what we want. We want the `ECHO` to be processed for every single file, so I simply split it into multiple lines.

```
@ECHO OFF

REM Iterate over all *.avi file in the current directory
FOR %%f IN (*.avi) DO (
    REM Cut off the extension from %%f, tack on .txt and 
    REM use it as the filename for our HAPPY output
    ECHO HAPPY > %%~nf.txt
)
```

Comment: Hi,
Thank you sooo much!! it works and I am HAPPY. 
just one more thing...
i am trying to understand how the loop thing is working. the clips that I am interested in are divided into many sub folders. so I have a main folder, inside many more folders, each folder containes another level of folders and the clips are inside the third level. and I want to do the same thing you taught me for all those folders but instead of copying the bat file you gave me and run it for each of the sub folders I want to be able to do it from the outer folder (the main one) automaticly.   
Thank you again!!!!
Shir

Comment: so I wrote this: FOR /r %%f IN (*.avi) DO (
%%~nf.txt
ECHO Philips > %%~nf_Medical_System.txt
)                                                                             but the txt file are located where the bat file is ...and I want each txt file to be under its movie.. how can I locate it in the subfolder it belongs? 
Thank you again!!!!                                                                                                                                                                             
Shir

Comment: and also, are the files must be localy on my computer in order for it to work?

Comment: @shir Try using `%%~dpnf.txt` instead. It should then use the Drive Letter + Full Path + Name + `.txt`. Maybe that will help. Otherwise make sure to let me know :)

Comment: You are the best! thank you! it is working perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Create a text file named **happy.txt** containing "**HAPPY**".  Create a batch file named **makehappy.cmd** containing this:

```
for %%i in (*.avi) do copy happy.txt "%%i.txt"
```

Run **makehappy**.  The new text files will have a double extension, but there are ways around that if necessary.